# Difference between '[:]' and '[::]' slicing when copying a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, slice

We can (shallow) copy a `list` by using `[:]`:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
z1 = l[:]
```

We can also (shallow) copy it by using `[::]`:

```
z2 = l[::]
```

and now `z1 == z2` will be `True`. I understand how these slices work after reading the answers in [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

But, my question is, is there any difference between these two internally? Is one more efficient than the other in copying or do they do exactly the same things?

Comment: It's the first colon that makes it a slice, the second doesn't change anything. You could come up with various other options (`[0:]`, `[::1]`, ...) but they do the same thing.

Comment: that question doesn't really answer my question, though, i know what makes slices i was just wandering if a difference exists betwen them

Comment: While this question might be covered by http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/674064, it is much more specific than http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/674064 and has merit of its own. Thus voting for re-opening.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/13005464/674064 I conclude that, no, there probably isn't any difference between `l[:]` and `l[::]`. But I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Absolutely no difference between them, *at least in Python 3*. You can check the byte-code produced for each of these using `dis.dis` if you'd like:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Byte-code emitted for `l[:]`:

```
from dis import dis
dis('l[:]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 BUILD_SLICE              2
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

while, byte-code emitted for `l[::]`:

```
dis('l[::]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 BUILD_SLICE              2
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

as you can see, *they're exactly the same*. Both load some `None`'s (the two `LOAD_CONSTS`'s) for the values of `start` and `stop` used for building the slice (`BUILD_SLICE`) and apply it. `None`s are the default for these as stated in the docs for `slices` in the [Standard Type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Special read-only attributes: `start` is the `lower` bound; `stop` is the upper bound; `step` is the `step` value; each is `None` if omitted. These attributes can have any type.

Use `[:]`, it's less key-strokes.

---

It's actually interesting to note that in Python `2.x` the byte code generated is different and, due to less commands for `l[:]` it might be *slightly* more performant:

```
>>> def foo():
...     l[:]
... 
>>> dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (l)
              3 SLICE+0             
              4 POP_TOP             
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

While, for `l[::]`:

```
>>> def foo2():
...     l[::]
... 
>>> dis(foo2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (l)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 BUILD_SLICE              3
             15 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             16 POP_TOP             
             17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Even though I haven't timed these (and I won't, the difference should be tiny) it seems that, due to simply less instructions needed, `l[:]` might be slightly better.

---

This similarity doesn't of course exist *only for lists*; it applies to all Sequences in Python:

```
# Note: the Bytecode class exists in Py > 3.4
>>> from dis import Bytecode
>>>
>>> Bytecode('(1, 2, 3)[:]').dis() == Bytecode('(1, 2, 3)[::]').dis() 
True
>>> Bytecode('"string"[:]').dis() == Bytecode('"string"[::]').dis() 
True
```

similarly for others.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [Python language reference section 6.3.2, Subscriptions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions), the inner expression for a sequence must evaluate to either an integer or a slice. Both these examples produce the same slice, and are therefore identical. There are also numerous other slices that have the same effect, by explicitly stating defaults (`start=0`, `stop=len(sequence)` or more, `step=1`).